# How do I access DI registered instance from within POCO?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, dependency-injection, .net-core

This is in a .NET Core project. In the Startup I register a singleton for my translation service that gets initialized with configuration settings from appsettings.json. Once it's set the whole app will use that service. This works great in my controllers and repositories, I just define the constructor to take that interface and it injects as expected:

```
services.AddSingleton<Foo.Bar.ITranslationService>(
    new Foo.Bar.SomeTranslator(config.TranslationSettings));
```

But the issue I ran into is one where a POCO needed to use that translation service. And my POCOs all get generated as generics by the repository, so for example a repository method might look like this:

```
public TEntity GetById(object id){
    return connection.Get<TEntity>(id);
}
```

So the repository has the injected TranslationService passed into it, but is there a way to cleanly pass that along to the POCO that needs it using DI? Or do I need to hack it somehow? I'm trying to figure out the cleanest way to do this, thanks!

Comment: POCO do not tend to have dependencies. Defeats the purpose of being a POCO. This appears to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @Nkosi yeah that's how it feels to me as well, I was hoping the question would elicit some other ideas. The challenge is that the developers using this POCO are not experienced so it would be easiest to just expose a property to them that would handle their translation using the service. I'm struggling to think of another way to tackle it that obfuscates the inner workings of all this from them and makes it easy to use

Comment: You might be misusing the term *POCO*. From reading the question, I understand that you are talking about *Entities*. A POCO could be anything from a domain layer component (containing behavior) that uses constructor injection to an Entity, from a DTO to a command message. You might want to update your question and title to reflect this.

Comment: In [Dependency Injection Principles, Practices, and Patterns](https://manning.com/seemann2) we describe that entities might have dependencies in their domain methods, but you should *not* use constructor injection in that case but instead use method injection (see section 4.3).

Comment: In other words, in case your `Job` class contains a `GetDescription` method that requires the `ITranslationService`, you should change the signature to `GetDescription(ITranslationService service)`, i.e. *use method injection*. In that case the consumer of `GetDescription` (typically a domain service) will get the dependency injected (into its constructor) and passes that same dependency on (using method injection) to the `Job.GetDescription` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about property injection?

```
public TEntity GetById(object id){
    var entity = connection.Get<TEntity>(id);

    if (entity is ITranslatable t)
    {
        t.Translator = _translationService;
    }

    return entity;
}
```

Comment: Yeah that's all I've been able to come up with too. It feels a little hacky but it would certainly work

Comment: Yes, I know what you mean. I think some kind of translation service that the POCOs get passed into would be cleaner. It was just off the top my head.

Answer (score 0):

You basically need to add the translation interface to the constructor of that object.

```
public class MYPOCO
{
    private Foo.Bar.ITranslationService translator
    public MYPOCO(Foo.Bar.ITranslationService translator)
    {
        this.translator = translator;
    }
}
```

This then allow you to use the translator service in the class. But your going to run into a number of issues there.

- Unless the framework explicitly creates your POCO then it will not
  get injected. For example it would need to be a Controller of some
  sort that would be created by the framework as soon as a route is
  called.
- You may need your own factories to create instances of the POCO.
- To keep the POCO as clean as possible, you probably want a Factory, which would create an instance of your POCO and set the translations appropriately. The Factory would take an instance of the translator service.

Comment: I'm not sure the constructor option is available? It looks like the thing that needs the translation dependency is being created by something else: `return connection.Get<TEntity>(id);`